# Does it make sense to develop open source python library for database inspection?

Tags: python, database

Some time ago I came up with an idea for a library for database inspection. I started developing it and got some very basic functionality, just to check if that's possible. Recently however, I get second thoughts, whether such project would really be useful. I am actually planning to develop following software suite:

- library for `python`, that would provide easy interface to inspect database structure,
- desktop application in `PyQt` that would use the interface to provide graphical database inspection,
- web application in `Django` that would use the interface to provide database inspection through the browser.

Do you think such suite would be useful for other developers/database administrators/analysts?

I know, that there is pgadmin for `PostgreSQL` and some tool for `sqlite3` and that there is `Java` tool called `DBInspect`. Usually I would be against creating new tool and rather join existing project, but I am not `Java` programmer (and I would rather stick to `python` or `C`, which I like) and none of these projects provide a library for database inspection.

Anyway I would like to hear some opinions from fellow developers, whether such project make sense or I should try to spend my free time on developing something else.

Comment: Hey, what I really need to be able to do in Python is sort of "Run Stylecop" on SQL Tables and stored procedures - e.g. check naming conventions, find and complain about implicit joins. I also want to be able to map a name of stored proc to the list of all tables that it modifies as well as depends on, as well as map every table to a list of stored procedures which read and write to it. I would like to be able to group pure getters, pure setters, and hybrids together. Redgate has a similar tool but I do not want to pay, and I want an open source library. Also, properly analyzing T-SQL is hard.

Comment: These are nice features: finding all tables that stored_procedure works on and finding all stored_procedures, that operate on table. I'd definitely would like to code something like this.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. I would gladly start using your code :) Remember, however, that there are some stored procedures which both look at some tables and write to others. It would be nice to separate those. Then there is another complication - temporary tables can be created. Then there is dynamic SQL ... ouch! Then there is the fact that the exact SQL syntax is vendor-dependent. MSFT SQL Server is my personal favorite.

Comment: Good, I can start coding then :-)

Comment: I have created a very early version of python package for accessing the database schema. If anyone is interested, it can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/fathom/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? You were already developing the library, and if you think the front end tools would be useful to you, it would probably be useful to someone else as well. I know I'd like a better front-end to SQLite (I use the Firefox plugin but I'm not too fond of it). If yours is decent, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Getting a tiny bit off-topic, but re SQLite—I use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/), and it's usable, although [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index) looks pretty cool.

Comment: Totally agree with @Frustrated. It sounds like a cool project, and when you are done, you'll have a really slick app in your portfolio to show off to potential employers/clients. And you'll be a Python stud.

Answer (score 1):

> database inspection through the browser.

Seems to be a waste of time.

Before I would ever connect a web application up to a database, I'd have **designed** that database.  I wouldn't be attempting to "discover" what's in it.

Discovery is a kind of reverse engineering exercise for developers or DBA's.

A command-line tool that used a standardized data access language would be ideal.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how command-line tool should work? Could you explain, why command-line tool would be better than access through browser? What I have in mind is that sometimes I need to change database, when I deploy new version of django app. Instead of using `psql` and 'ALTER|CREATE|..' to change the database, I would use web app to do that.

Comment: @gruszczy: How does one Django app prepare the database for another, different Django app in a secure, reliable, trustworthy manner?  It sounds like too much Django and not enough design, code, test and deploy.  I can't see a use case for using a web-based app to doctor the database for a web-based app.  It sounds too complex to setup and too insecure to manage.

Comment: What I have in mind is just a different interface for the same operations, that desktop client would provide. Say you want to delete a table in `PostgreSQL`. You can either run `psql` and `DROP TABLE` or `pgadmin`. I would like to add third option, through web app. Especially that Authentication backend can be written to authenticate in whatever way you want. Crap, those comments aren't the best way for this discussion. Some mailing list or forum would be better :-/

Comment: @gruszczy: A web app to build web apps is an inherently bad idea.  You can keep explaining, but it's a security and configuration nightmare.  Web Apps can't be trusted like commandline or desktop apps.  I would never, never take the time to build, configure and maintain a web app that does the same thing the command-line does.  It's a security nightmare for no recognizable benefit.

Comment: @gruszczy: "comments aren't the best way"  Right.  That's why you can **update** your question.

Comment: If I decide to develop a web app I'll contact you for sure, to get some insight about security issues. Thanks a lot for your comments, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @gruszczy: "security issues".  Only half the problem.  The other half is this.  I would never, never use a web application to help me build web applications.  It makes little to no sense because of the peculiar circularity of it.   The web is a very, very large hammer.  Reverse engineering a database is a very, very small screw.  I don't see the point in pounding that small screw with a very large hammer.  I'd rather have a small screwdriver.  On the desktop.

Comment: That's why I will develop also a `PyQt` desktop application. These are three technologies that I love and I would like to be able to interact with each of them in a single project. Anyway, are you always so skeptical towards web apps? I have to say that, that often choose web apps over desktop ones, e.g. I'd rather use google docs, rather than Open Office.

Comment: @gruszczy: "always so skeptical towards web apps".  I write web apps.  "I would never, never use a web application to help me build web applications."

Comment: I see :-). Thanks for your input, I'll keep in mind your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing sounds a bit like Toad (http://www.toadworld.com/) a free program I use.  It can store database connection info for you, browse it through a GUI, and run SQL in a window.  Is there something else specific that you want your application to do?

If it's to sharpen your skills then go for it, it sounds like a worthwhile project; but no need to reinvent the wheel if you can get what you want through open source software.